# Increment Index in $_POST Array

Tags: php, loops, increment, do-while

I have a section of php code where I need for the $_POST index to increment by one each time it goes through the `"do while"` loop. In other words, the first occurrence would be `$_POST['tableserver1']`, then the next one would be `$_POST['tableserver2']`, etc. This loops 6 times and then stops.

I have tried using variables as the index, trying to get them to increment. I found an example in the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php which increments the number at the end of a string, but I'm not having any luck with getting it to work inside the `$_POST` index.

This section of code creates a set of 6 select lists that contain names from the database. I am trying to get the select lists to populate from the `$_POST` value if it is set, other wise it is zero.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $x = 1;

do {
    ?>
    <blockquote>
        <p><?php echo $x . "."; ?>
            <select name="tableserver<?php echo $x; ?>" id="tableserver<?php echo $x; ?>">
                <option selected value="0" <?php
                if (!(strcmp(0, '$tableserver.$x'))) {
                    echo "selected=\"selected\"";
                }
                ?>>Select Server</option>
                        <?php
                        do {
                            if (strpos($row_getnamesRS['service'], '22') !== false) {
                                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row_getnamesRS['memberID'] ?>" <?php
                        if (!(strcmp($row_getnamesRS['memberID'], '$tableserver.$x'))) {
                            echo "selected=\"selected\"";
                        }
                        ?>><?php
                                    echo ucfirst(strtolower($row_getnamesRS['first_name']))
                                    . "&nbsp;" . ucfirst(strtolower($row_getnamesRS['last_name']))
                                    ?></option>
                        <?php
                    }
                } while ($row_getnamesRS = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnamesRS));
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($getnamesRS);
                if ($rows > 0) {
                    mysqli_data_seek($getnamesRS, 0);
                    $row_getnamesRS = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getnamesRS);
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
    </blockquote>
    <?php
    $x++;
} while ($x <= 6);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i=0;
do{
   echo $_POST['someval'.$i];
}while(++$i < 6)
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was trying to do. Somehow I must have had my syntax wrong. But this works! Thank you!

Comment: With this I was able to eliminate 27 lines of code that were used to define the post variables.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this? ...

```
$arr = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
    array_push($arr, $_POST["tableserver" . $i]);

$arr; // Contains 6 values (starting from $_POST["tableserver1"] to $_POST["tableserver6"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to post an an array

so instead of

```
name="tableserver<?php echo $x; ?>"
```

use

```
name="tableserver[]";
```

the you can just do

```
foreach($_POST['tableserver'] as $tableServer){....}
```